# Swift UITableView Unknown Crash on Reload

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have a tableview controller with two sections. The first one is loaded immediately and always has just one row while the second contains objects downloaded from Parse asynchronously. No matter what I try, I always get some unknown error that crashes my app when trying to reload the tableview. I set an exception breakpoint and it triggers on the reloadData call / reloadSections. If I comment this line out it works fine, but obviously doesn't update. I have tried:

- reloadData and reloadSections
- Loading the objects in viewDidLoad.
- Loading the objects in viewDidAppear.
- Loading the objects using dispatch_async on the main thread.
- Loading the objects using dispatch_after on the main thread after two
  seconds.
- reloadData and reloadSections on the main thread.
- I have also verified that the request executes successfully.

I am using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3

Here is the code where I fetch the objects:

```
  var classes = [PFObject]()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let relation = user.relationForKey(classesKey)
    let query = relation.query()
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        self.classes = results as! [PFObject]
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And here are my tableViewDataSource implementations:

```
  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
      return 1
    case 1:
      return self.classes.count
    default:
      assert(false, "ERROR: Bad Section")
      return 0
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    switch section {
    case 0:
      cell?.textLabel?.text = (self.mode == LXMode.Learn) ? "Add Classes You Need Help With" : "Add Classes You Want to Tutor"
    case 1:
      let classObject = self.classes[indexPath.row]
      cell?.textLabel?.text = classObject.objectForKey("name") as? String
      cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = classObject.objectForKey("departmentPrefix") as! String + "-" + String(classObject.objectForKey("number") as! Int)
    default:
      assert(false, "ERROR: Bad Section")
      break
    }
    return cell!
  }
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Instead of reloading just the section, try reloading the entire tableview and place the breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath & numberOfRowsInSection. And try to find out the reason behind the crash. While you do so check if you are on main thread or not.

Comment: Hi @KumarNitin, I tried this. After calling all of the relevant delegate methods the crash occurs.

Comment: What does "some unknown error" mean?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried calling reloadData on the main thread

```
var classes = [PFObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let relation = user.relationForKey(classesKey)
    let query = relation.query()
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
          println(error.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        self.classes = results as! [PFObject]

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I tried this as well with both reloadSections and reloadData and had the same result with both.

Comment: While it is true that you may only update the UI on the main thread, `reloadData` doesn't update the UI.  Moreover, none of the `UITableViewDelegate` methods actually update the UI either.  The Apple-written code within the table view is what is actually updating the table view, and I would be extraordinarily surprised if Apple was letting that thread depend on what thread you called `reloadData` on (rather than forcing it to the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out - there was nothing wrong with my code. Rather, the interface was messed up in the storyboard. When I deleted it and recreated it it finally worked.

Answer (score -3):

It appears like you're trying to reload the UITableView from a background thread. UIKit only allows access to controls from the main thread and will throw an exception. You can use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) to marshal back to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
```

You'll run into this with ANY UIKit classes and must always call into them from the main thread. The docs are a good reference for GCD:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html

Comment: Hi @jblair! Thank you for the suggestion. But I tried this with both reloadSections and reloadData and had the same result.

Comment: @AttilaTheFun Are you possibly getting an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`? If so this is usually the result of your UITableView's datasource not matching your requested edits to the table. For example, your data source describes only one section (index 0) and you're telling the table to update the second (index 1) which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: While it is true that you may only update the UI on the main thread, `reloadData` doesn't update the UI.  Moreover, none of the `UITableViewDelegate` methods actually update the UI either.  The Apple-written code within the table view is what is actually updating the table view, and I would be extraordinarily surprised if Apple was letting that thread depend on what thread you called `reloadData` on (rather than forcing it to the main thread).

Comment: @nhgrif You're correct that `reloadData` doesn't directly update the UI the way a `UIView`'s `drawRect:` does. However, it updates the internal state of a UI object which can cause internal inconsistency (for example, when `UITableView` starts reloading from its data source). While you're not guaranteed a crash by accessing UIKit from a background thread, the general rule of thumb with all UI toolkits on all platforms is that they are not thread-safe APIs and you should only access them from the main thread.

Comment: Are you confident that when `reloadData` is called that `UITableView` calls its data source methods on the same thread as `reloadData` was called on, or does it for all of the data source/delegate calls to the main thread?